# Calling method on Template variables giving "undefined" exception

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-output

I have one parent containing two child components.

```
AppComponent
     NotificationsComponent
     MoveCopyComponent
```

I want to emit values of MoveCopyComponent to NotificationComponent. Whenever I emit i get a property undefined in the NotificationComponent as shown in the screenshot
[image]

```
<notifications #notificationsMenu role="menuitem" dropdown-item 
       [caller]="'menu'" 
       (acceptShareFromMenuEvent)="shareAcceptModal.PinItem($event)"                                                                         
       (contentShareAccepted)="shareAcceptModal.hide()">
</notifications>
```

And down below we have declared a component which pops a modal to place the content.

```
<movecopy-item #shareAcceptModal 
    (shareAcceptedandPlaced) = "notificationItem.contentAccepted($event)">

</movecopy-item>
```

A button click in the modal(movecopy component) **shareAcceptedandPlaced** event is triggered by which I need to execute **contentAccepted(..)** method in my notifications component as below.

```
shareAcceptedandPlaced(){
       this.shareAcceptedandPlaced.emit(this.sharedItemPinnedInfo);     
}
```

What is happening here is that the notifications component contains the collection of the incoming components while the move-CopyItem is merely a selection component to place the incoming component.

When the #shareAcceptModal raises the "(shareAcceptandPlaced)" event for the "notificationItem's" contentAccepted() method, I get the following exception:
"Cannot call contentAccepted on undefined. as in the above screenshot"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Refine your post once to give clear information. I read your post and it does not convey exact information. I got a idea about your problem and I had one such situation. But need little more information. are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: Thanks Aravind, I have added a few more details. I am unavailable on TV, but available on Skype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mistakes**

1. You cannot call the child component method like

   ```
   (shareAcceptedandPlaced) = "notificationItem.contentAccepted($event)"
   ```
2. You are emitting a Output() variable which is not a child of notifications in your event `shareAcceptedandPlaced()`

**Solution**

1. Since you have AppComponent as a parent, you can use @ViewChild()
   for both the child components and access the properties and methods
   of your both child components as

   ```
   @ViewChild(movecopyComponent) mcopyComp: movecopyComponent;
   @ViewChild(NotificationsComponent) notificationMenu: NotificationsComponent;
   ```
2. Modify your method call in the `<movecopy>` as below

   ```
   <movecopy-item #shareAcceptModal (shareAcceptedandPlaced)="myContentChanged()">
   </movecopy-item>
   ```
3. You can have your myContentChanged() method to handle it as

   ```
   myContentChanged() {
          this.mcopyComp.properties....
          let temp: {...};        
          this.notificationMenu.contentAccepted(temp);
   }
   ```